# How to animate change of state made by React this.setState({})?

Tags: reactjs, animation

I am rendreing the DOM element, which get data from the local state. With the press of a button, state changes with this.setState({}) and DOM element re-renders it. How to animate that change of state?

Git: https://github.com/TyroniUA/v.rudovtsymbalist-gmail.com

```
<StepsCard number='01' 
  id='number-one' 
  numberbckg='#00A9E7' 
  h2width={this.state.h2width[0].one} 
  h2={this.state.displayText[0].title} 
  p={this.state.displayText[0].text} />

<StepsCard 
  number='02' 
  id='number-two' 
  numberbckg='#B9D67B' 
  h2width={this.state.h2width[0].two} 
  h2={this.state.displayText[1].title} 
  p={this.state.displayText[1].text} />
```

Comment: First of all you should be specific about your problem here.
Secondly, Best way to achieve that is using css

Comment: Hi. My issue is that I have a container, where displayed text changes from the input of the user. Text changes due to this.setState({}) function. My question was how to make text change more smooth to the user.

CSS doesn't work on this.setState or I am wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by making text change smooth? Also please share your code.

Comment: Hi, I edited + provided code. There is a change of state in StepsCard. Change of state in terms of displayed content. When state changed - content appears immediately. How to make it appear in o.5 seconds like fading in?

Comment: What library you are using? Can you add a class to your <StepsCard /> component?

Comment: What do you mean by the library? SCSS in terms of stylesheets. I can add a class in SCSS sure, but what exactly should I mention? The transition only works when the component loads the first time. After the change of the state - it doesn't load again with transition property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `react-transition-group` package for that.
just import TransictionGroup and CSSTransition from that component and wrap your JSX you need to animate. It requires a key on basis of which you need to animate, that is some state in your case.

```
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

      <TransitionGroup>
        <CSSTransition key={this.state.value} timeout={1000} classNames="messageout">
         <YOURJSX/>
        </CSSTransition>
      </TransitionGroup>
```

Here is an example of it: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-dubinsky-zmwpu

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply again, but it doesn't work. Simple transition doesn't make any difference with className. I can set background color - sure. But when inside component there are changes of the state - it doesn't render them with the transition.

Comment: Can you create an example of your code in codesandbox?

Comment: I would like to play around with the code, just create an example of your stepscard component, and share the link

Comment: https://github.com/TyroniUA/v.rudovtsymbalist-gmail.com - git. I also added it to the main post

Comment: Can I contribute to it?

Comment: Go on, just create separate branch

Comment: But please provide solution here also, so someone othe can also find it useful

Comment: I was able to do that in your project which might need some minor changes, how can I show it to you, should I open a PR?

Comment: Can you create a separate branch and submit?

Comment: you can review and merge the code and change it as per desire : https://github.com/TyroniUA/v.rudovtsymbalist-gmail.com/pull/1

Comment: Thanks it works. But only with p, Number and H2 doesn't accept animation. Do you mind if I will write in PM?

Comment: Didn't find any PM button, so can you find me on facebook?